# Python Selenium get parent element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

My html code looks like:

```
<li>
  <div class="level1">
    <div id="li_hw2" class="toggle open" </div>
  <ul style="" mw="220">
    <li>
      <div class ="level2">
        ...
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I am currently on the element with the id = "li_hw2", which was found by

```
level_1_elem = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "li_hw2")
```

Now i want to go from level_1_elem to class = "level2". Is it possible to go to the parent li and than to level2? Maybe with xpath?
Hint: It is neccassary to go via the parent li and not directly to the element level2 with

```
self.driver.find_element(By.Class_Name, "level2")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best-suited locator for your usecase is xpath, since you want to traverse *upward* as well as *downwards* in the HTMLDOM.

```
level_1_elem = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='li_hw2']")
```

and then using `level_1_elem` web element, You can do the following :

1. to directly go to `following-sibling`

   ```
   level_1_elem.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//following-sibling::ul/descendant::div[@class='level2']")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the html i think the `ul` should group all the `li` if it s the case then it s easy if not i realy dont get that html.

```
//div[@class="level1"]/parent::li/parent::ul/li/div[@class="level2"]
```